# Active Directory Administrative Center Crashes when updating object

Tags: active-directory, windows-7, windows-server-2012-r2, windows-10

DSAC.exe crashes every time we try to update a user object. It will crash in every system we try it on including the servers running Active Directory. It happens on Windows 7, Windows 10, and Windows 2012 R2.

I posted the event logs on [technet](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/24fffb70-8795-404c-a6e4-9a320487f25e/active-directory-administrative-center-crashes-when-updating-object?forum=winserver8gen) as well but no one has provided any input yet.

The event logs are too long to post here directly.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I have this same problem.  I did the same thing.  Someone from MSFT suggested I apply a years old update and reinstall RSAT after applying the update. Workaround is use Active Directory Users and Computers or Powershell to do your work until ADAC is fixed or just reopen ADAC after it crashes every time you do something.

Answer (score 3):

**Update 3/14/2017**:

It's fixed: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4013429/windows-10-update-kb4013429

---

As was already mentioned, this was a bug that was shipped with the 12B (mid-December) 2016 patches.

The issue is fully understood and has been debugged internally, and the fix was scheduled to be released as part of the 2B (mid-February) release cycle, however, as you can read about on the [MSRC blog](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/msrc/2017/02/14/february-2017-security-update-release/), the updates are being delayed to March.

Technically, the ADAC crash has two causes. One, there is some code in the .NET framework (which ADAC relies upon) that calls `GetLastError` when it shouldn't. Two, there was a subtle change in kernel-mode GDI window ordering code that caused one of its functions (`EnableWindow`) to set last error when it shouldn't.

While we wait for the fix, some workarounds that have helped others include:

1. Change the desktop color depth to 16 bit (win 7 only)
2. Maximize the management console window
3. Disable the "Enable desktop composition" performance option (win 7 only)
4. Apply the Windows Basic theme

For reference, here is a screenshot of what the error looks like:

[image]

Comment: Fully patched to today with Windows 7 it seems to work with just the "3.Disable the "Enable desktop composition" performance option (win 7 only)" and windows default theme as suggested by Ryan Ries above.

Answer (score 2):

Security patches KB 3205394, 3206632, 3205386 crash Active Directory Admin Center

https://www.askwoody.com/2017/security-patches-kb-3205394-3206632-3205386crash-active-directory-admin-center/

The Windows patches mentioned in the article seem to be the culprit.

KB3205394 and KB3207752, which is mentioned by KB3205394 are the culprit in Windows 7. However so is kb3207752. Once all three were removed, it resolved the issue.

In Windows 10, remove KB 3206632 and 3205386 depending on the build number you have.

I'm not sure what these updates are changing. We created a test box and fully updated it to the latest patches and it is not experiencing the issue. So why are the other systems breaking the Administrative Center?

Comment: I am also having this problem. Just to clarify, is it KB 3205394, 3206632, 3205386 that are breaking it in Server 2012 R2?

Comment: KB3205394 is for Windows 7 and Windows 2008

KB3206632 and KB3205386 are for Windows 10. I'm not sure if these apply to Windows 8.1 and Server 2012r2.

I think for Windows 8.1/Server 2012r2 will be KB3205400 and KB3205401

http://www.infoworld.com/article/3155264/microsoft-windows/december-windows-security-patches-crash-active-directory-admin-center.html

Answer (score 1):

I had the problem too. I even uninstalled and installed ADAC. It didn't help.

**CrypticSage** is right. Just to mention it --> i also had the Problem on Windows Server 2012 (without R2). It seems, that the problematic updates for this os are: **KB3205409** and **KB3205403**

so uninstall them and it will work again.

Maybe this helps someone...

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to fix it! uninstall update KB3212646 – January, 2017 Security Monthly Quality Rollup for Windows 7. If that alone doesn't fix it for you, check to see if you also have KB3207752, because KB3212646 includes "improvements" from KB3207752. This page will reference any other related updates.  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3212646/january-2017-security-monthly-quality-rollup-for-windows-7-sp1-and-win The work around for disabling "enable desktop composition" allowed me to make changes in active directory administrative center, but uninstalling this update actually fixed the issue.