# Active Directory Administrative Center (Server 2012 R2) crashes frequently upon updating user

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2

[image]

Is this the same error referenced here: [Active Directory Administrative Center Crashes when updating object](https://serverfault.com/questions/824239/active-directory-administrative-center-crashes-when-updating-object/) ?

I tried posting this image *IN THE SAME THREAD*, which seems to make the most logical sense instead of spawning new questions as I am doing here, however *since you can't post images in comments*, the only place I could post an image was as an *answer*, and it was deleted.

Comment: Yes, it is a possible duplicate.  I POSTED THAT IN MY QUESTION.  I'm trying to add USEFUL INFORMATION to that thread, but it was deleted.  How can I add a screenshot of the error?

I don't know if that thread is referencing the same error, which is why I am trying to post a picture of the error.

Comment: @Daniel, my answer to the question that you already referenced is the real answer. There's no need to ask any further questions on this particular issue. I'll post your picture for you in my answer.

Comment: @Ryan Thank you. That's all I wanted to know, because no one was referencing the ACTUAL ERROR in that thread.  They were just saying that "it crashes".  There are various ways that an application can crash, with or without errors, for instance, or with various different errors.  Without that crucial information, how else would one know if the answers in the thread applied to them?

Comment: @Daniel You posted a question as an answer. That's why I deleted your answer.

Comment: To clarify - SF is not a forum, and it doesn't have "threads". It as questions, answers, and comments. Your post should have been a comment.

Comment: @EEAA I completely agree with that concept, and it makes PERFECT SENSE.  However, as far as I am aware (and correct me if I'm wrong), there is no way to post an image in a comment.

Comment: You can post a link. Or preferably just the text of the error, which gets indexed by search engines.

Comment: A fair point.  The ability to put images in comments would still make a lot of sense.  I can see how it would make scrolling through a question more unwieldy, but at least it could be a thumbnail which you could click to expand.